# TFS2010 - How can you change the "State" for a Task?

Tags: tfs-workitem

We are using Tasks to track individual development items and the "out of the box" configuration gives us only 2 states **- Active** and **Closed**.  We would like to change it to:

1. Assigned
2. In Development
3. In Test
4. Ready for Production
5. Closed (In Production)

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  We've been through everything in the Admin site.  I fine changing it in the DB if necessary but am not sure what should be changed - or if it is even in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are defined by the project template you selected when you created your project (MSF Agile for instance).

To customize, you can [export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253051(VS.80).aspx) your existing template(s), modify as needed, then [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253163(VS.80).aspx) them back in.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849(VS.80).aspx) is the MSDN link for customizing work item types. And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404845(VS.80).aspx) is the link for changing the workflow of a work item type (seems like you'd need to do this too).

Comment: Thanks for the references Adam!